# Mudar o target de um elemento com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso passar esse código em `JavaScript` para `jQuery`? Não entendi o contexto...

`document.getElementById("imageForm").target = "my_iframe";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa mudar isso para jQuery. Claro que pode mudar mas lembre-se que jQuery é JavaScript e só vai fazer com que o mesmo código seja corrido no final. Ou seja o jQuery vai correr exatamente esse código no final, mas passando por mais código antes e ficar mais lento. Se não é necessário não use jQuery.

O contexto aqui é no caso de ter uma iFrame na página querer que uma ancora abra nessa iframe em vez de abrir na mesma página. O valor que der a esse `target` tem de coincidir com a propriedade `name` da iFrame.

Se quiser fazer isso em jQuery, pode fazer assim:

```
$('#imageForm').attr('target', 'my_iframe');
```

Exemplo do contexto:

```js
document.getElementById("minha_iframe").target = "minha_iframe";
```

```html
<iframe src="" id="minha_iframe" name="minha_iframe"></iframe>
<a href="http://cnn.com" target="minha_iframe">Abrir o link na iFrame</a>
```

Comment: Acho que o contexto é mudar o target de um formulário da janela principal para o iframe.